# Need to Map incoming column to different field in model class

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, modelmapper

I am receiving jpa object from db using springboot and mapping it to model but the column name in model is different than the  one coming from database.

I tried to setter to set the value of model field from the incoming database attribute but the attribute is in parent class
and hence it is always set as null.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your field has the name foo you can use the `@Column` annotation to declare a db column with a different name so

```java
class Model {
    // other fields
    @Column(name = "bar")
    private int foo;
}
```